# Getting View in some non Activity class

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-activity

I am new to `Android`, I am working on a project about which I need to customize some views. I need to get some `imageview` from a layout that was inflated in some `BaseAdapter` like class (the following `UserListAdapter` class).

```
public class UserListAdapter extends SingleTypeAdapter<User> { 
    ...
    protected void update(int position, User user) throws IOException {
        ....
        View view = activist.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.user_list_item,null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_avatar);
        ....
    }
}
```

First, I need to get the `current` view, that's the reason why I added some `activist` in the `SingleAdapter` `class` which inherits from `TypeAdapter` (which is the one class that inherits from `BaseAdapter`)

```
public abstract class SingleTypeAdapter<V> extends TypeAdapter {

protected Activity activist = null;

public SingleTypeAdapter(final Activity activity, final int layoutResourceId) {
    this(activity.getLayoutInflater(), layoutResourceId);
    activist = activity;
}
```

But in the `update` `UserListAdapter` method, the `activist` is null. How can I get the current view from the `UserListAdapter` class ?

Update, here's the `TypeAdapter` class

```
/*
 * Copyright 2012 Kevin Sawicki <kevinsawicki@gmail.com>
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.github.kevinsawicki.wishlist;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

/**
 * Base adapter
 */
public abstract class TypeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  /**
   * Updater for current view
   */
  protected final ViewUpdater updater = new ViewUpdater();

  /**
   * Initialize view by binding indexed child views to tags on the root view
   * <p>
   * Sub-classes may override this method but must call super
   *
   * @param view
   * @param children
   * @return view
   */
  protected View initialize(final View view, final int[] children) {
    return updater.initialize(view, children);
  }

  /**
   * Set current view that is currently being updated
   *
   * @param view
   */
  protected void setCurrentView(final View view) {
    updater.setCurrentView(view);
  }

  /**
   * Get indexed children
   *
   * @param parentView
   * @return children
   */
  protected View[] getChildren(final View parentView) {
    return updater.getChildren(parentView);
  }

  /**
   * Get text view at given index
   *
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @return text view
   */
  protected TextView textView(final int childViewIndex) {
    return updater.textView(childViewIndex);
  }

  /**
   * Get text view at given index
   *
   * @param parentView
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @return text view
   */
  protected TextView textView(final View parentView, final int childViewIndex) {
    return updater.textView(parentView, childViewIndex);
  }

  /**
   * Get image view at given index
   *
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @return image view
   */
  protected ImageView imageView(final int childViewIndex) {
    return updater.imageView(childViewIndex);
  }

  /**
   * Get image view at given index
   *
   * @param parentView
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @return image view
   */
  protected ImageView imageView(final View parentView, final int childViewIndex) {
    return updater.imageView(parentView, childViewIndex);
  }

  /**
   * Get view at given index
   *
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @return view
   */
  protected <V extends View> V view(final int childViewIndex) {
    return updater.view(childViewIndex);
  }

  /**
   * Get view at given index
   *
   * @param parentView
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @return view
   */
  protected <V extends View> V view(final View parentView,
      final int childViewIndex) {
    return updater.view(parentView, childViewIndex);
  }

  /**
   * Set text on text view at given index
   *
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @param text
   * @return text view
   */
  protected TextView setText(final int childViewIndex, final CharSequence text) {
    return updater.setText(childViewIndex, text);
  }

    /**
   * Set text on text view at given index
   *
   * @param parentView
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @param text
   * @return text view
   */
  protected TextView setText(final View parentView, final int childViewIndex,
      final CharSequence text) {
    return updater.setText(parentView, childViewIndex, text);
  }

  /**
   * Set text on text view at index to string resource
   *
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @param resourceId
   * @return text view
   */
  protected TextView setText(final int childViewIndex, final int resourceId) {
    return updater.setText(childViewIndex, resourceId);
  }

  /**
   * Set text on text view at index to string resource
   *
   * @param parentView
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @param resourceId
   * @return text view
   */
  protected TextView setText(final View parentView, final int childViewIndex,
      final int resourceId) {
    return updater.setText(parentView, childViewIndex, resourceId);
  }

  /**
   * Set text on text view to be formatted version of given integer number
   * <p>
   * This method uses the formatter returned from
   * {@link NumberFormat#getIntegerInstance()}
   *
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @param number
   * @return text view
   */
  protected TextView setNumber(final int childViewIndex, final long number) {
    return updater.setNumber(childViewIndex, number);
  }

  /**
   * Set text on text view to be formatted version of given integer number
   * <p>
   * This method uses the formatter returned from
   * {@link NumberFormat#getIntegerInstance()}
   *
   * @param parentView
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @param number
   * @return text view
   */
  protected TextView setNumber(final View parentView, final int childViewIndex,
      final long number) {
    return updater.setNumber(parentView, childViewIndex, number);
  }

  /**
   * Get child view
   *
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @param childViewClass
   * @return child view
   */
  protected <T> T getView(final int childViewIndex,
      final Class<T> childViewClass) {
    return updater.getView(childViewIndex, childViewClass);
  }

  /**
   * Get child view
   *
   * @param parentView
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @param childViewClass
   * @return child view
   */
  protected <T> T getView(final View parentView, final int childViewIndex,
      final Class<T> childViewClass) {
    return updater.getView(parentView, childViewIndex, childViewClass);
  }

  /**
   * Set child view as gone or visible
   *
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @param gone
   * @return child view
   */
  protected View setGone(final int childViewIndex, boolean gone) {
    return updater.setGone(childViewIndex, gone);
  }

  /**
   * Set child view as gone or visible
   *
   * @param parentView
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @param gone
   * @return child view
   */
  protected View setGone(final View parentView, final int childViewIndex,
      boolean gone) {
    return updater.setGone(parentView, childViewIndex, gone);
  }

  /**
   * Set the checked state of the {@link CompoundButton} with at index
   *
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @param checked
   * @return check box
   */
  protected CompoundButton setChecked(final int childViewIndex,
      final boolean checked) {
    return updater.setChecked(childViewIndex, checked);
  }

  /**
   * Set the checked state of the {@link CompoundButton} with at index
   *
   * @param parentView
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @param checked
   * @return check box
   */
  protected CompoundButton setChecked(final View parentView,
      final int childViewIndex, final boolean checked) {
    return updater.setChecked(parentView, childViewIndex, checked);
  }

  /**
   * Set the text on the text view if it is non-empty and make the view gone if
   * it is empty
   *
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @param text
   * @return text view
   */
  public TextView setVisibleText(final int childViewIndex,
      final CharSequence text) {
    return updater.setVisibleText(childViewIndex, text);
  }

  /**
   * Set the text on the text view if it is non-empty and make the view gone if
   * it is empty
   *
   * @param parentView
   *
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @param text
   * @return text view
   */
  public TextView setVisibleText(final View parentView,
      final int childViewIndex, final CharSequence text) {
    return updater.setVisibleText(parentView, childViewIndex, text);
  }

  /**
   * Set relative time span on text view
   *
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @param time
   * @return text view
   */
  public TextView setRelativeTimeSpan(final int childViewIndex, final long time) {
    return updater.setRelativeTimeSpan(childViewIndex, time);
  }

  /**
   * Set relative time span on text view
   *
   * @param parentView
   * @param childViewIndex
   * @param time
   * @return text view
   */
  public TextView setRelativeTimeSpan(final View parentView,
      final int childViewIndex, final long time) {
    return updater.setRelativeTimeSpan(parentView, childViewIndex, time);
  }
}
```

Comment: is the constructor of the `SingleTypeAdapter` called before the `update` method?

Comment: @mvieghofer Sorry I am very new to `Android`, so I don't know when  the `update` is called. It seems to be processed automatically, as the `getView` method, isn't it ?

Comment: set a breakpoint in the constructor and the update method and debug your app. Then you will see which method is called first.

Comment: I use `intellJ`, I get some validate red icon on the `SingleTypeAdapter` method and some error cross on the `update` method but I don't know which method was called first

Comment: sorry I don' use intelliJ so i don't know what that red icon means

Comment: anyway, it is highly probable that update is called before the constructor, so how can I get the activity so to inflate it ? By the way, in this very `update` method, this line `setText(1, String.format("%1$s %2$s", user.getUsername(), user.getEmail()));` works well, so this method seems to be able to add text to the view that was previously inflated, so how can I set some `setBackgroundDrawable` to the ìmageview` that the layout contents? Is there  any `setImage` (setText like) method ?

Comment: If you don't have access to `getActivity` or something like this, I don't think you have access to the view. What is `TypeAdapter`? I don't know that class..

Comment: @mvieghofer I have edited my post with the entire `TypeAdapter` class

Comment: who calls the update method? the updater? Also I'm not sure if you really need to extend the BaseAdapter. I would rather extend a subclass such as ArrayAdapter since a lot of functionality is already implemented.